# How can I delete selected object from scene using sceneform?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

```
 private AnchorNode anchorNode;
 private void removeAnchorNode(Node nodeRemove) {

        //Remove an anchor node
        if(nodeRemove instanceof  AnchorNode){

            if(((AnchorNode)nodeRemove).getAnchor() != null) {
                ((AnchorNode) nodeRemove).getAnchor().detach();
            }
        }

        if (!(nodeRemove instanceof Camera) && !(nodeRemove instanceof Sun)) {
            nodeRemove.setParent(null);
        }
    }
```

My delete function is above

```
FloatingActionButton dlt =(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.delete);
        dlt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //delete();
                removeAnchorNode(anchorNode);
            }
        });
```

and in this part I call the function, but all the time when it's working it just deletes the last added object, then it's not working for other object. Where is my fault? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Your removeAnchorNode function seems proper enough. The problem probably lies in the way that you are 'choosing' the anchorNode.

I guess you're probably storing the last created `AnchorNode` in the anchorNode object that you created, thus the delete function works initially.
But when you do it again, the node you want to delete needs to be selected. Although Sceneform takes care of selecting the node(when you touch it), you need to explicitly store the reference in your anchorNode variable since otherwise you'd simply be passing the already deleted `AnchorNode` again and again.

Comment: Hi, mark the answer as correct if it works(or feel free to add your own answer if the issue was something else), cheers.